# Nginx: Permission denied for nginx on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, debian, vagrant, puppet

I am new to system administration. After installing nginx [via puppet](https://github.com/kasperisager/puppet-nginx) on Ubuntu I get the following output:

```
[alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)

[warn] 1898#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1

[emerg] 1898#0: open() "/var/log/nginx/access.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

How do I get rid of all of these messages?

I don't want to use command line directly (chown / chmod) and repeat it every time I create a new server. Therefore, I am thinking of what has to be added to the puppet manifest.

What is the best sysadmin practice in this case: to change owner / permissions for /var/log/nginx or to store logs in different location? If chown / chmod is the way to go, which specific permissions would ensure the highest level of security?

I tried this, but it didn't help:

```
  file { '/var/log/nginx':
    ensure  => directory,
    mode    => '0755',
    owner   => 'www-data',
    group   => 'www-data',
    recurse => true
  }
```

Edited:

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ ps aux | grep [n]ginx
root      1001  0.0  0.1  62908  1388 ?        Ss   08:47   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data  1002  0.0  0.1  63260  1696 ?        S    08:47   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  1003  0.0  0.1  63260  1696 ?        S    08:47   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  1004  0.0  0.1  63260  1696 ?        S    08:47   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  1005  0.0  0.1  63260  1696 ?        S    08:47   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

Comment: Are you sure the puppet code was applied (using `vagrant provision` for example)? Is `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` using `www-data` or `nginx` to run nginx non-master processes?

Comment: check already running ports once, if nginx ports `443` or `80` if incase they are used by other process, it may cause the similar error. use command `sudo netstat -tulpn` to check whether the ports 80 or 443 is used by other process.

Answer (score 248):

Make sure you are running the test as a superuser.

```
sudo nginx -t
```

Or the test wont have all the permissions needed to complete the test properly.

Comment: Does this mean the 3 alerts/warnings meantioned by OP can simply be ignored as long as `sudo nginx -t` works fine and the nginx master process has sudo privileges?

Answer (score 48):

I faced similar issue while restarting **Nginx** and found it to be a cause of **SeLinux**. Be sure to give a try after either disabling SeLinux or temporarily setting it to *Permissive* mode using below command:

`setenforce 0`

I hope it helps :)

Comment: `setenforce 0` for selinux backed-in distros (Redhat, Centos, Fedore, ...) is indeed a very valid answer if you are 100% sure that you set the permissions correct on the directory.

Comment: It's a very valid answer if you 100% don't care about security...

Answer (score 41):

If i assume that your second code is the puppet config then i have a logical explaination, if the error and log files were create before, you can try this

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/nginx;
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/log/nginx;
```

Comment: Potential security problem with that `chmod` - it also sets all log files as executable. Do this instead: `sudo chmod -R u+X /var/log/nginx`

Comment: i would never do that for it's a security flaw. same rule for apache: logs must be owned by root not the working user

Answer (score 10):

just because you don't have the right to acess the file , use

```
chmod -R 755 /var/log/nginx;
```

or you can change to sudo then it

Comment: You don't want your logs to be readable to anyone except the root.

Comment: But do I want to be running nginx as root?

Comment: Similar answer in [How do I configure nginx to put its error.log file somewhere I have write privileges?](//stackoverflow.com/a/42617427)

Answer (score 9):

if you don't want to start nginx as root.

first creat log file :

`sudo touch /var/log/nginx/error.log`

and then fix permissions:

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/nginx`

`sudo find /var/log/nginx -type f -exec chmod 666 {} \;`

`sudo find /var/log/nginx -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

Answer (score 5):

Permission to view log files is granted to users being in the group adm.

To add a user to this group on the command line issue:

```
sudo usermod -aG adm <USER>
```

Comment: What, if any, are the downsides to this approach?

Comment: adm: Group adm is used for system monitoring tasks. Members of this group can read many log files in /var/log, and can use xconsole. Historically, /var/log was /usr/adm (and later /var/adm), thus the name of the group.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) I had to use:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/log/nginx
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I just changed the selinux from enforcing to permissive and then I was able to start nginx without any error.

Comment: Disabling selinux defeats the purpose of selinux.  Yes, it's a quick ends to a means -- but it's not necessarily the correct ends to the means.  Better to learn the correct way to work with selinux.

Comment: selinux is a god for production and an evil for development.

Answer (score 0):

Found a [good description](https://torstenwalter.de/openshift/nginx/2017/08/04/nginx-on-openshift.html) what to do.

```
    # support running as arbitrary user which belogs to the root group
    RUN chmod g+rwx /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx
    # users are not allowed to listen on priviliged ports
    RUN sed -i.bak 's/listen\(.*\)80;/listen 8081;/' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    EXPOSE 8081
    # comment user directive as master process is run as user in OpenShift anyhow
    RUN sed -i.bak 's/^user/#user/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Fixing all the issues with running NGNIX without root.

Answer (score -1):

I just patch nginx binary replacing path `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and other with local path.

```
$ perl -pi \
    -e 's@/var/log/nginx/@_var_log_nginx/@g;' \
    -e 's@/var/lib/nginx/@_var_lib_nginx/@g;' \
    -e 's@/var/run/nginx.pid@_var_run/nginx.pid@g;' \
    -e 's@/run/nginx.pid@_run/nginx.pid@g;' \
    < /usr/sbin/nginx > nginx
$ chmod +x nginx
$ mkdir _var_log_nginx _var_lib_nginx _var_run _run
$ ./nginx -p . -c nginx.conf
```

It works for testing.

Answer (score -4):

This works for me,

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/log/nginx
```

Answer (score -5):

Nginx needs to run by command `'sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start'`

Comment: I couldn't get sudo service nginx restart to work, got this output: `service nginx restart
Failed to restart nginx.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files`, but `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart` worked like a charm for me.