# why nginx not starting my service?

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am using linux fedora, i installed nginx as `sudo yum install nginx`.I have created a django project and assigned a port as `guicorn  projectname.wsgi:application --bind=127.0.0.1:8001`.And i created a file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

in my `default` file i have the following code:

```
server {
   listen localhost:8006;

   location / {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
   }

   location /static/ {
   autoindex on;
   alias /home/user/Desktop/projects/28-05-2014/HMS/static/;
}
}
```

When i checked my nginx server home as `localhost:80` it is running.But when i called `localhost:8006` it is not connecting. When i checked active connections with `netstat -lnt | grep 80` i found only nginx default service is running.What mistake i am doing.Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Have you reloaded nginx?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, Yes i have restarted many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the above code in `nginx.conf` file which is located in `/etc/nginx/`.Then your configuration file looks like this

### nginx.conf

```
server {
   listen localhost:8006;

   location / {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
   }

   location /static/ {
   autoindex on;
   alias /home/user/Desktop/projects/28-05-2014/HMS/static/;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not enough information to answer.

Enable logging:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/example.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/example.error.log;
```

And look at what the log files says. If you cannot figure it out, please post the log outputs here. Question does not provide enough data. I ll update this answer as you update your question.

Comment: modified file restarted the server and given request but nothing happen.Even the files also not created.First server is not listing any request to write log files

Comment: Looks like you have permission issues. follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714902/nginx-on-ubuntu-permission-denied