# nginx permission denied when try start

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, centos

I was googled alot but not find a solution for this, i am trying start nginx after a basic config, and i am getting the following error:

```
Set 21 23:57:53 vps.medjy.ml nginx[21444]: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
Set 21 23:57:53 vps.medjy.ml nginx[21444]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/srv/www/medjey/logs/access.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
Set 21 23:57:53 vps.medjy.ml nginx[21444]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Set 21 23:57:53 vps.medjy.ml systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Set 21 23:57:53 vps.medjy.ml systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.
```

The file of vhost /etc/nginx/sites-available/medjey are same this below:

```
    server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name medjey;
    access_log /srv/www/medjey/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/medjey/logs/error.log;
    root /srv/www/medjey/public_html;
    location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    include         fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

and the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf are same this:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
## Load virtual host conf files. ##
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

I alredy changed all permissions and owners possible, but its still not up the service.

CentOS 7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx: Permission denied for nginx on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714902/nginx-permission-denied-for-nginx-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, just need change on /etc/sysconfig/selinux to `SELINUX=permissive`  and adjust the vhost on servername change for the IP.

Comment: Sorry, what is the new servername for that?  I'm having the same issues on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

Use **sestatuss** to check whether the firewall is open or not.

I also faced same issue . 
Just disable the Selinux